# What is the technolpgy, does Facebook/Youtube Notification Systems use?

Tags: websocket, push-notification, notifications, xmpp, server-sent-events

I am currently working on an web application, which need to implement a notification system, just like Facebook and Youtube does. (Not mobile PUSH Notification. Just to show how many notifications are in the notification couter and, when soneone expand it, show all notifications. Just as Facebook) What I need to know is, what is the following best method to use.

1.Websocket

2.SSE

3 XMPP

Our application is on budget and, we are running it on a VPS server.